# Enumerating Microsoft Edge History Programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, microsoft-edge

I used FindFirstUrlCacheEntry/FindNextUrlCacheEntry Win API to get Internet Explorer's history programmatically in C++.

Can you tell me how to get Microsoft Edge History using C++ (Windows API)?

Comment: I have found and posted detailed answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885973/15065

Answer (score 2):

Not possible at this point in time.  Might want to use the 'suggestions routes' at some of the links below.

Developer Feedback Home - https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer

Developer Feedback Twitter - https://www.twitter.com/msedgedev

Feature Suggestions - https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/category/18985-web-browsing

Healy in Tampa

Answer (score 1):

The history is stored in \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat. It uses Microsoft’s Extensible Storage Engine to store data. There is a [C++ wrapper for accessing Extensible Storage Engine files](https://github.com/fakechris/esent) I've used to access data from this file.

The "Containers" table inside WebCacheV01.dat tells which "Container_X" tables have type of "Content" or "History", as well as the Secure Directories and their order. You can use the [ESEDatabaseView utility](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ese_database_view.html) to view the data inside the WebCacheV01.dat file.