# c# read Microsoft Edge History

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge

I couldn't figure out how to get Edge history in c#.
I've tried this code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + "Container_n";
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=" + @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat" + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
OleDbDataAdapter dsCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
//Fill the DataSet object
dsCmd.Fill(ds, "Packets");
myConnection.Close();
```

But the row `dsCmd.Fill(ds, "Packets");` throws:

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

I don't want to install it on every computer that I use the app on.
Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of accessing the Edge browser history. It looks like you are trying to access the history of the MS Edge legacy browser. Correct me if you are using the Edge chromium-browser. Here I want to confirm with you does your code worked if you install oledb provider? I try to search and found that you can also use the JetAttachDatabase API to open that file but unfortunately I did not get any document about it. Here is the thread link may helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747766/how-to-read-the-microsoft-edge-history-using-c-sharp

Comment: I noticed that you want to read data from .dat file. Depending on whether the .dat file type is binary or text, the reading method differs. Use the static functions of the File class to complete reading in two formats.
Binary format: `File.ReadAllBytes`
Text format: `File.ReadAllText`.